# Convert arrays of arrays to object with key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have arrays of arrays which contains something like this:

```
var values = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]]
```

I've tried .map() and Object.assign but I dont know how to implement it. I want this as an output:

```
values = [
    {'up': 1, 'middle': 2, 'down': 3},
    {'up': 3, 'middle': 2, 'down': 1}
]
```

What should I use? This is what Im came up so far:

```
const object1 = [[1,2,3],[3,2,1]],
  object = []

object1.forEach(function(array) {
   object.map(value => ({'up': array[0], 'mid': array[1], 'down': array[2]}))
 });

console.log(object)
```

Comment: what is the expected output. always put 1st, 2nd or 3rd index or sort it first then arrange?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not very different from what others already did, but a little more elegant:

```js
let arr = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]];

let result = arr.map(([up, middle, down]) => ({up, middle, down}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I'd say not only a little more elegant but so much simpler it's clearly the one correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

you can simply use `Array.map()`, there is no need of `forEach()`

```js
let arr =[[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]];

let result = arr.map((e)=>({"up" : e[0], "mid"  : e[1], "down" : e[2]}));
console.log(result);
```